# Codesandbox.io sending back html data instead of Json data

Tags: json, reactjs, codesandbox

I'm currently working on a code problem on codesandbox where I am trying to use a http get request to retrieve json data from the link provided. However, when I console.log the response, I'm only receiving html data, which I have never seen before when making an http request. Has anyone else run into this issue with displaying JSON data and have tips for using codesandbox?

Thank you!

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "../styles.css";
import axios from "axios";

export default function App() {
  axios
    .get(`www.sbir.gov/api/solicitations.json?keyword=sbir`)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `console.log(response)`
Try
`console.log(response.json())`

Comment: I'm receiving an error that "response.json" is not a function

Comment: Did you put pranthesis at the end of 'json'?

Comment: yes I have console.log(response.json()); while the error reads "TypeError: response.json is not a function"

Comment: Ok fine, kindly try 'response.data'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this is the case, but you need to use `https`.

In your case you should be using `https://www.sbir.gov/api/solicitations.json?keyword=sbir` instead of `www.sbir.gov/api/solicitations.json?keyword=sbir`.

I found an example codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/get-requests-from-json-using-axios-forked-0zf6b?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark), when you remove `https://`, console logging the response outputs a html script.